# MariaDB extract json nested data

Tags: sql, json, database, mariadb

I have following SQL query and trying to extract nested json data field.

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       created_at: 2023-01-05 14:25:52
       updated_at: 2023-01-05 14:26:02
       deleted_at: NULL
          deleted: 0
               id: 2
    instance_uuid: ef6380b4-5455-48f8-9e4b-3d04199be3f5
    numa_topology: NULL
     pci_requests: []
           flavor: {"cur": {"nova_object.name": "Flavor", "nova_object.namespace": "nova", "nova_object.version": "1.2", "nova_object.data": {"id": 2, "name": "tempest2", "memory_mb": 512, "vcpus": 1, "root_gb": 1, "ephemeral_gb": 0, "flavorid": "202", "swap": 0, "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "vcpu_weight": 0, "disabled": false, "is_public": true, "extra_specs": {}, "description": null, "created_at": "2023-01-05T05:30:36Z", "updated_at": null, "deleted_at": null, "deleted": false}}, "old": null, "new": null}
       vcpu_model: {"nova_object.name": "VirtCPUModel", "nova_object.namespace": "nova", "nova_object.version": "1.0", "nova_object.data": {"arch": null, "vendor": null, "topology": {"nova_object.name": "VirtCPUTopology", "nova_object.namespace": "nova", "nova_object.version": "1.0", "nova_object.data": {"sockets": 1, "cores": 1, "threads": 1}, "nova_object.changes": ["cores", "threads", "sockets"]}, "features": [], "mode": "host-model", "model": null, "match": "exact"}, "nova_object.changes": ["mode", "model", "vendor", "features", "topology", "arch", "match"]}
migration_context: NULL
         keypairs: {"nova_object.name": "KeyPairList", "nova_object.namespace": "nova", "nova_object.version": "1.3", "nova_object.data": {"objects": []}}
  device_metadata: NULL
    trusted_certs: NULL
           vpmems: NULL
        resources: NULL
```

In flavor: section i have some json data and i am trying to extract `"name": "tempest2"` value in my question but it's nested so i am not able to find way to extract that value.

My query but how do i remove `[]` square brackets in value

```
MariaDB [nova]> select uuid, instances.created_at, instances.deleted_at, json_extract(flavor, '$.cur.*.name') AS FLAVOR from instances join instance_extra on instances.uuid = instance_extra.instance_uuid;
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| uuid                                 | created_at          | deleted_at          | FLAVOR       |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| edb0facb-3353-4848-82e2-f12701a0a3aa | 2023-01-05 05:37:13 | 2023-01-05 05:37:49 | ["tempest1"] |
| ef6380b4-5455-48f8-9e4b-3d04199be3f5 | 2023-01-05 14:25:51 | NULL                | ["tempest2"] |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

**#Update**

This is the MariaDB version I have

```
MariaDB [nova]> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------------------------+
| VERSION()                                 |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 10.5.12-MariaDB-1:10.5.12+maria~focal-log |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? The implementation of JSON support in MySQL is different from MariaDB, and I see that the prompt says MariaDB.

Comment: I have updated question with version info.

Comment: `$.cur."nova_object.data".name`. You just need double quotes around the key that contains `.`.

Comment: Oh!! i was using single quote but didn't realize to use double quote. Now it looks good. I can see double quotes in output like `"tempest1"` but i think i can live with that. It would be good if we can remove `"` quote :)

Comment: Try [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_unquote/), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BaAVE87t).

Comment: You folks can add your solution in answer so i can upvote it